# Sequelize error using Node.JS, Express.JS Sequelize and SQLite3

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, sequelize.js

Can anyone help me. I am building an Inventory Management System using Node.JS, Express.JS Sequelize and SQLite3.

I have encountered an error:

```
throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`);
      ^

Error: Supplier.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
    at Supplier.belongsToMany (D:\projects\stockwise\api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:33:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\stockwise\api\models\supplierModel.js:34:10)        
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\stockwise\api\models\orderModel.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
```

Here is my code:

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../config/database");
const Product = require("./productModel");
const PurchaseOrder = require("./orderModel");

class Supplier extends Model {}



Supplier.init(
  {
    supplier_id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    supplier_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    contact_information: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Supplier",
    tableName: "suppliers",
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);

Supplier.belongsToMany(Product, { through: "product_supplier" });
Supplier.hasMany(PurchaseOrder);

Supplier.sync()
  .then(() => {})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  }); // Create the "Supplier" table in the database if it doesn't exist

module.exports = Supplier;
```

I have tried different ways of defining the model and associations, but nothing is working.

My code seems fine to me and that it should work.

If anyone can help and explain this to me, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Add the product model as well